# The function "json_populate_recordset" does not exist in Postgres

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I created a function stored in a temporary table json data popularized columns. But when I run it does not recognize the **json_populate_recordset** function.

**Create the sequence proveedorcuadrillarecurso_seq**

```
CREATE SEQUENCE proveedorcuadrillarecurso_seq
  INCREMENT 1
  MINVALUE -9223372036854775808
  MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
  START 1
  CACHE 1;
```

**Create the table proveedorcuadrillarecurso**

```
CREATE TABLE proveedorcuadrillarecurso
(
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('proveedorcuadrillarecurso_seq'::regclass),
  idproveedorcuadrilla integer NOT NULL,
  idrecurso integer NOT NULL,
  cantidad numeric(10,2) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT pk_proveedorcuadrillarecurso PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

**Create the function proveedorcuadrillarecurso_nuevomasivo_pa**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION proveedorcuadrillarecurso_nuevomasivo_pa(
    par_idproveedorcuadrilla integer,
    par_data text
)
RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    var_IDPARENT INT;
    var_IdRecurso INT;
    var_Cantidad NUMERIC(10, 2);
BEGIN
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE "#tablaExtra"(
    parent_ID INT NOT NULL,
        IdRecurso INT,
        Cantidad NUMERIC(10, 2),
        procesado INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
    );

    INSERT INTO "#tablaExtra" 
    SELECT * FROM json_populate_recordset(null::"#tablaExtra", par_data);

    WHILE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM "#tablaExtra" WHERE procesado = 0) LOOP
        SELECT parent_ID, IdRecurso, Cantidad 
        INTO var_IDPARENT, var_IdRecurso, var_Cantidad
        FROM "#tablaExtra"
        WHERE procesado = 0
        ORDER BY parent_ID NULLS FIRST
        LIMIT 1;

    BEGIN
            INSERT INTO ProveedorCuadrillaRecurso (IdProveedorCuadrilla, IdRecurso, Cantidad)
            VALUES (par_IdProveedorCuadrilla, var_IdRecurso, var_Cantidad);
    COMMIT;
        EXCEPTION
            WHEN OTHERS THEN
        BEGIN
             RAISE NOTICE 'Ocurrio un Error Inesperado... Consultar con el Administrador de Servicios!';
        END;
        END;

        UPDATE "#tablaExtra"
        SET procesado = 1
        WHERE parent_ID = var_IDPARENT;
    END LOOP;
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "#tablaExtra";
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

**Excecute Query::**

```
select proveedorcuadrillarecurso_nuevomasivo_pa(1,'[{"parent_ID":67272,"IdRecurso":123,"Cantidad":152,"procesado":0}]');
```

**Error:**

```
ERROR:  function json_populate_recordset("#tablaExtra", text) does not exist
LINE 2:     SELECT * from json_populate_recordset(null::"#tablaExtra...
                          ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
QUERY:  INSERT INTO "#tablaExtra" 
    SELECT * from json_populate_recordset(null::"#tablaExtra", par_data)
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function proveedorcuadrillarecurso_nuevomasivo_pa(integer,text) line 27 at SQL statement
********** Error **********

ERROR: function json_populate_recordset("#tablaExtra", text) does not exist
SQL state: 42883
Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
Context: PL/pgSQL function proveedorcuadrillarecurso_nuevomasivo_pa(integer,text) line 27 at SQL statement
```

I got method's reference from http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html

Comment: Try `SELECT * FROM json_populate_recordset(null::"#tablaExtra", par_data::json);`